# Simple rails named routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck with this simple named route problem. I have:

```
#Controller:

  def show
    @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])
  end

#Routes.rb:

  match '/:name' => 'things#show'
```

The response I get is `Couldn't find Thing without an ID`. If I change the controller to:

```
@thing = Thing.find(params[:name])
```

Then I get `Couldn't find Thing with ID=thing`. What am I missing?

Comment: In fact, you are not using named routes at all. Most common named routes are those generated by `resources :things` and that allow you to use `things_url` and other path/url helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@thing = Thing.find_by_name(params[:name])
```